# Multiplication of two numbers without crossing the data type size limit?

Tags: arrays, math, module, factorial

Suppose i have been asked to find the factorial of first 1000 numbers and to store them in an array of size 1000. i.e
array[0] = 1, array[1] = 1! = 1, ...., array[6] = 6! = 720 and so on.
But not to exceed the data size, i have been provided with the module value mod.
Now this is what i'm doing.

```
i = 1;
array[0] = 1;
while(i <= 1000)
{
    array[i] = (i*array[i - 1])%mod;++i;
}
```

The problem i am facing is at a certain point the value of (i*array[i - 1])%mod becomes 0, and from there all the factorial values up to 1000 gets 0 value.
example - for mod value 3414

```
array[568] =  2844
array[569] =  0
array[570] =  0
array[571] =  0
```

and so on.
Kindly help me as what should i do to avoid this unfortunate thing. I don't know if this is right or wrong. Like if i have to use the factorials in an another mathematical formula, then it'll either addition of nothing or multiplication by 0(whichever be the case). Is it acceptable? If it's not then what can be done.

Comment: Could you edit to include what you think is unfortunate about this result?  (Hint: what are the factors of 3414?)

Comment: @DSM edited as per required.

Comment: I would recommend working out on paper what you think `array[569]` should be.

Comment: I don't think you've made any mistakes.

Comment: @GregS - consider this case sir, suppose i have to find the value of -
f(1000) = 1000*((1000!) + 1000), where 1000! denotes the factorial of 1000 which in this case is zero due to the use of mod, is it wrong that the answer becomes 0 or just because the problem statement has provided with a mod value, 0 is acceptable as answer?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but it is a fact that 1000! mod 3414 = 0. It's not right or wrong or acceptable or unacceptable it is simply a mathematical fact.

Answer (score -1):

Find a function to test the size of "i" at runtime (should be an int, normally 32 bits, so 2^32) and if the generated value is greater than this size, break the loop.